# Linking to specific page in external pdf file on Android

Tags: android, pdf, latex, pdflatex, hyperref

I'm trying to make a pdf index file that links into other pdf documents at specific pages. Using pdfLaTeX and hyperref, I managed to obtain such an index.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
Link to orange document, page 2: \href{file:orange\#page.2}{go to orange page}
Link to same document: \hyperlink{h:apple}{go to the Apple Page}
```

However, this only works when I view it on desktop computers. For example, with Adobe Reader it works fine.

When I view the index on Android, the results depend on the viewer.

1. On some viewers, links to external pdf files won't work at all - which is likely a problem with the viewer itself. Links to the index document itself may work or not, but this is not the issue. Viewers in this category: Adobe Reader, qPDF Viewer.
2. On other viewers, links to the index document itself do work, but links to other pdf documents open the target document at the beginning - not at the target page. Viewers in this category: ezPDF Reader.

So, here's the question: is there something I'm doing wrong? I would think I'm doing it right, since it does work on desktop computers. I suppose I need a reader on Android that understands links to specific pages in external documents. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX is independant of the device that is used. It is suposed to look the same in every device. So the problem is the Viewer.